# provisioning profile error after Xcode update

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

After updating to xcode8.1 I am getting this error

> A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.

Before that everything is working fine.

What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi. Can you attach more details? E.g. screenshot of build-log.

Comment: What Xcode did you upgrade from?  If it was from Xcode 7.X, Xcode 8 may have switched you over to automatic provisioning, or have similarly messed up your code signing settings.  Show your provisioning and code signing settings in your project.